# Today's date in utc formatted in epoch

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I need to use `utc` epoch to match the correct Stackoverflow API values and the API uses the date without time as a filter parameter.

See the example on final to this page:
https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/no-answer-questions#fromdate=2022-05-11&order=desc&sort=creation&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true

I tried converting via `.timestamp()`:

```
date_today = datetime.utcnow().date()
date_final = date_today.timestamp()
```

But this error appeared:

```
AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'timestamp'
```

How should I proceed if `timestamp` only works for the complete value with date and time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to feed it a timestamp integer. You should do this with

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
utc_timestamp = datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc).timestamp()
round(utc_timestamp)
```

Clarification - Per FObersteiner's comment,

`datetime.utcnow()` is dangerously timezone-unaware.

For me, this function returns a result that is off by 14,400 seconds from actual UTC time, because it's using my local machine's localized timezone (Eastern Daylight Time).

For example, running this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

utc_now_stamp = round(datetime.utcnow().timestamp())
datetime_now_stamp = round(datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc).timestamp())

utc_now_stamp - datetime_now_stamp
```

Yields a difference of
`14400`. Avoid using `utcnow()`.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for the UTC epoch timestamp of like, 12:00:00 AM for today's date?

Comment: (Epoch time is intrinsically in units of seconds, i.e. any epoch time necessarily represents one precise second in time)

Comment: Hi @RobertBoscacci, in this way indicated by you the stackoverflow API does not accept, I tried. It only needs to be today's date, no time.

Comment: Please, see the example on final on this page: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/no-answer-questions#fromdate=2022-05-11&order=desc&sort=creation&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true

Comment: When I run `datetime.utcnow().timestamp()` I get a float value, e.g. `1652300340.219999`. I think you need to use some integer in the API, you could use `round(datetime.utcnow().timestamp())`

Comment: Again, an epoch time is necessarily an exact time to the second, so when you say "no time" that just doesn't fit this paradigm

Comment: ```round(datetime.utcnow().timestamp())``` is perfect for my case, please edit your answer with this option so I can mark it as solved!

Comment: You'll want to set tzinfo to UTC, then call `.timestamp` - https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/11/utcnow.html